# Format date of any form of date implementation in java

Tags: java, date

I looking for a function which will format date into given format if type of date or any other implementation else throw exception

Eg: 
formatDate(java.util.Date date)
Or
formatDate(org.joda.time.LocalDateTime)
or 
formatDate(any valid date implementation)
eg: java.time.LocalDateTime , javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar or other date time implementation

I cannot be sure for the type of date i receive so don't ask me to implement same date type everywhere in project

Comment: Did you look at [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) ?

Comment: Use Java method overloading?

Comment: When you receive a `Date` or `XMLGregorianCalendar`, just convert them to a `LocalDateTime`. Then you can base all your other code on that class, regardless of how you initially receive it.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);` for example will format into a string such as: 2019-07-25T15:05:54.432

Other formats are available, practically every standard format you could want is included as a static constant in the class. However, it also supports custom patterns, the following page explains how to create these: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Two options that I would at least consider:

1. One method that takes an `Object` argument. Inside the method do a long chain of `if`-`else` using `instanceof` to find the right type. If you want to support the `java.sql` types that extend `java.util.Date` (an awful hack), remember to test for those first because `instanceof java.util.Date` will also be true. Down side: Your user will not get a compile-time error for passing an unsupported type and may find it difficult to find out why your method throws an exception given a `String` or an `Integer`, for example (which *may* represent dates too).
2. An overloaded method for each supported type, as @MarkB suggested in a comment. Down side: You need to modify your API for each new supported type added.

Whether you choose one option or the other, convert whatever you get to something that implements `TemporalAccessor` and pass it to `DateTimeFormatter.format()`.

Just mentioned as a curiosity, `String.format()` already implements some of the functionality you envision. It handles `TemporalAccessor`, `Calendar`, `Date` and `Long`.